# How to add id (primary key) when insert a multi-dimensional php array into a mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, sql-insert

I created this mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE earthquakes (
 id INT(20) AUTO_INCREMENT,
 idserial VARCHAR(30),
 milliseconds BIGINT,
 latitude FLOAT,
 longitude FLOAT,
 magnitude FLOAT,
 ipocentro FLOAT,
 source VARCHAR(4),
 region SMALLINT,
 PRIMARY KEY(id),
 INDEX indice_idserial(idserial),
 INDEX indice_milliseconds(milliseconds),
 INDEX indice_lat_lng(latitude,longitude),
 INDEX indice_magnitude(magnitude),
 INDEX indice_ipocentro(ipocentro)
);
```

And i want to insert a multi-dimensional php array into a mysql table but i dont'know like to add also `id`.

This is code to add array:

```
//MULTIDIMENSIONAL ARRAY
$array_database= array(
 array("2017-06-30-104",1498858541000,39.3322,-122.9027,2.11,0,"U",36)
);
//

foreach($array_database as $row) {
    $idserial_db= mysql_real_escape_string($row[0]); 
    $milliseconds_db = mysql_real_escape_string($row[1]);
    $latitude_db = mysql_real_escape_string($row[2]);
    $longitude_db = mysql_real_escape_string($row[3]);
    $magnitude_db = mysql_real_escape_string($row[4]);
    $ipocentro_db= mysql_real_escape_string($row[5]);
    $source_db= mysql_real_escape_string($row[6]);
    $region_db= mysql_real_escape_string($row[7]);  

    $valori_db[] = "('$idserial_db',$milliseconds_db,$latitude_db,$longitude_db,$magnitude_db,$ipocentro_db,'$source_db',$region_db)";
}
$values = implode(',', $valori_db); 


mysqli_query($connessione,"INSERT INTO earthquakes (idserial,milliseconds,latitude,longitude,magnitude,ipocentro,source,region) VALUES $values");
```

So how i add `ID` ?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english

**EDIT**
Maybe i should to add `ID` in this way:

```
 mysqli_query($connessione,"INSERT INTO earthquakes (id,idserial,milliseconds,latitude,longitude,magnitude,ipocentro,source,region) VALUES $values");
```

Comment: seems ok, what error you got?

Comment: in mysql_query (last line) maybe i should add also id field ?

Comment: id field is auto_increment so what issue you are getting

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam please see my edit

Comment: @Borja you don't need to add the ID in the query.. what error you got ?

Comment: I thought i needed to add it .... sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the declaration:

```
//MULTIDIMENSIONAL ARRAY
$array_database= array(
 array("", "2017-06-30-104",1498858541000,39.3322,-122.9027,2.11,0,"U",36)
);
//
```

In the loop:

```
 $valori_db[] = "    ('','$idserial_db',$milliseconds_db,$latitude_db,$longitude_db,$magnitude_db,$ipocentro_db,'$source_db',$region_db)";
```

In the query:

```
mysqli_query($connessione,"INSERT INTO earthquakes  (id,idserial,milliseconds,latitude,longitude,magnitude,ipocentro,source,region) VALUES $values");
```

Comment: No, your code is not wrong, but if you really need the ID in the query, that's the way you must do it.

Comment: but in my multidimensional array i don't have a first empty value... is a problem? no...right?

Comment: The empty value is for the ID. it will be created automatically because that column in the database is auto_incremental.

Comment: So that's why in my query I might also not include "id"